# Can you instantiate objects via a Property setter?

Tags: c#, properties

C#: can you instantiate objects via a Property setter?

eg.

```
private List<MyObject> myList;
public List<MyObject> MyListProperty { get {return myList;} set {myList = value;} }
```

THEN:

```
MyListProperty = new List<MyObject>();
```

Comment: Your property `MyListProperty` is missing a type specifier.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that is perfectly valid.
In the line `MyListProperty = new List<MyObject>();` you do not "*instantiate objects via a Property setter*". First, you instantiate a new list, and then you set `MyListProperty` to the list you've created. It is equivalent to:

```
List<MyObject> myObjectList = new List<MyObject>();
MyListProperty = myObjectList;
```

Next, if you want your code to compile you should specify the type of your property:

```
public List<MyObject> MyListProperty
{
     get {return myList;}
     set {myList = value;}
}
```